# Why is this roof covered in pigeons?

Tags: roof, pest

I was out walking the other day and observed something strange with one house having a number of pigeons congregating on the roof. (This is not my home, so I have no insight into internal details.) A took a photo, below.

It's a semi-detached home, but the birds were noticeably staying on one side. They wrapped around the home, on both the south and west faces of the roof. The roof has an owl decoy installed, so I gather this must be an ongoing problem.

It's cold out (5C/41F), so I figured the birds just gather around the exhaust vent. But then I'd expect to see them closer to the vent and on both sides of the home.

Then I thought maybe they are catching sun, because it's a south-facing roof. But then I would think this would happen on other houses' roof too.

Is this roof just poorly-insulated? Something else going on?

[image]

Comment: I don't really object to the question being closed, but I also think this is a fair question I, if I owned the home, would have asked my contractor (which is a welcome topic per help center?). As I mentioned in the question, the problem is very specific to that one home, which suggests the solution would also be home-related? But I agree there's no obvious home solution that can be offered without more details (which I cannot get), so I suppose that makes sense as grounds for close.

Answer (score 1):

Rock Pigeons (or Rock Doves) live almost exclusively in human structures. There must be a bridge or old mill building or something nearby.

Then, pigeons, like all other animals, operate under the guidance of their instincts. They're instinctively attracted to perches that offer a good vantage point to watch for predators, socialize, and move out to feeding areas. This home happens to be in a location that suits those biological imperatives.

I doubt that there's anything particular about the construction of the home that's attractive to the birds. They're mostly happy with its location, or rather the location of the perching surface.

Comment: I would agree+ is this 2 story maybe alone for a higher pirch than several homes? The large tree may also be blocking the wind to the location is more comfortable than other houses.

Comment: It might also be that whoever lives in that house feeds the birds. In our old neighborhood, there was a guy that sat in his driveway throwing birdseed all day long. His roof with lousy with birds, even when he wasn't out there.